# Count not empty cells next to each other

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I want to return "YES" in H4 when a total of 14 or more consecutive cells are filled with any text data in the range L4:NL4.

I do not want simply count "not empty cells" in this range but how many are not empty are not interrupted by blank cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something along the lines of:

```
=IF(MAX(SCAN(0,L4:NL4,LAMBDA(a,b,IF(b<>"",a+1,0))))>13,"Yes","No")
```